# Append Meta Data to URL

Tags: javascript, meta-tags

I have three meta variables: Concept, DocType and Path that I want to add to my URL so that I up with something in my browser that looks like "http://www.mywebsite.com/page.html?concept=var1&doctype=var2&path=var3

Right now my page has the following code on it, but I am very new to JS and not sure if this is correct:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<meta name="concept" content="product"  />
<meta name="docType" content="template"  />
<meta name="Path" content="offer"  />

<script>
function refresh() {
  var concept = document.querySelector('meta[name="concept"]');
  var doctype = document.querySelector('meta[name="docType"]');
  var path = document.querySelector('meta[name="Path"]');

  this.document.location.href = "?concept=" + concept.content + "&doctype=" + doctype.content + "&path=" + Path.content;

}
</script>

</head>

<body>
Line of text
<script>
    if (location.search.indexOf("concept") !== -1) refresh();
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

This gives me the following error with no changes to my url:

reflow: 0.1ms
reflow: 0.11ms
reflow: 0.14ms
1406128139877   Services.HealthReport.HealthReporter    WARN    No prefs data found.

Answer (score 0):

Use `querySelector` instead of `getElementByName`, and instead of `concept.value`, use `concept.content`. So your code would look like this:

```
<meta name="concept" content="product"  />
<meta name="docType" content="template"  />
<meta name="Path" content="offer"  />

<script>
function refresh() {
  var concept = document.querySelector('meta[name="concept"]');
  var doctype = document.querySelector('meta[name="docType"]');
  var path = document.querySelector('meta[name="Path"]');

  document.location.href = "?concept=" + concept.content + "&doctype=" + doctype.content + "&iapath=" + path.content;

}
</script>
```

Also, `iapath.content` is an error, use `path.content`, that's your variable's name.

In addition, you have to call the method `refresh` somewhere; otherwise it won't run:

```
<body>
Line of text
<script>
    if (location.search.indexOf("concept") === -1) refresh();
</script>
</body>
```

This piece of (static) html works perfectly on my local server on all browsers I have access to (chrome, firefox, IE...):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="concept" content="product"  />
    <meta name="docType" content="template"  />
    <meta name="Path" content="offer"  />
    <title>Test</title>
    <script>
    function refresh() {
        var concept = document.querySelector('meta[name="concept"]');
        var doctype = document.querySelector('meta[name="docType"]');
        var path = document.querySelector('meta[name="Path"]');

        document.location.href = "?concept=" + concept.content + "&doctype=" + doctype.content + "&iapath=" + path.content;

    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
Line of text
<script>
    if (location.search.indexOf("concept") === -1) refresh();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks I tried changing my code to that on the page, but it doesn't seem to change the url in the browser.

Comment: @mghurston Updated. Are there any errors? (Press Ctrl+shift+j)

Comment: No errors, this is my full page's code...ugh, can't put code in this comment so basicaly I just added standard HTML, Header, Body Tags with one line of text.

Comment: @mghurston Well you need to call `refresh()` somewhere.

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work - updated code snippet above to include what I have on the page.

Comment: @mghurston Sorry, minor typo. Change `location.search.indexOf("concept") !== -1` to `location.search.indexOf("concept") === -1`. :(

Comment: Thanks, I must be doing something wrong, nothing shows up extra in the url, I have the file as test.html and when I refresh the page it still just shows the url as test.html, not test.html?concept=concept&doctype=doctype&path=path

Comment: I should add, I have this code, I place it on my webserver and then I view the page in the browser and hit refresh. I assume I am missing a step here and that is why it is not showing up.